# show lastest useState update in react js

Tags: reactjs

Here I have an error state and fills by boolean if every input is vacant.

```
const [error, setError] = useState(false);

setError((prev) => {
        emptyInputs.forEach((key) => {
          prev[key] = true;
        });

        return { ...prev };
      });
```

In the next step, I wanna check if error length is equal 'zero' do something.

```
const setReadOnlyMode = () => {
    if (Object.keys(error).length === 0) {
        setCanEdit(false);
        setIsReadOnly(true);
        setIsDisabled(true);
    }
}
```

and execute it in button click event

```
<SaveModifiedInfosBtn updateCientInfo={() => isChanged && onSubmitHandler(info) && setReadOnlyMode()} margin="ms-3" />
```

But the problem is here that after second time click error fills by empty input name and first time click on button it returns empty array.

can anyone help me?

Comment: The data type of your state shouldn't change. You initiate your error state with a boolean (false), but afterwards you're trying to access Object.keys(error). This indicates to me that you're not expecting error to be a boolean. Please elaborate on what you want to save in error state.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your component, i.e. the `onSubmitHandler` function, the inputs and the parts that use `setError`

Comment: Excuse me. Im filling it by obj of empty input names at all and it does not includes by boolean value.

Comment: It's still a bit unclear what you are asking. Can you create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue and include a set of reproduction steps, and provide what the expected vs observed behavior is?